# How to make inference on cluster-specific parameters in a Bayesian mixture model

Tags: bayesian, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model, model-based-clustering

Suppose I have a mixture model, for example of the kind
$$
y_i \mid w, \{\theta_h\}, H \sim \sum_{h=1}^H w_h f(y_i \mid \theta_h) \\
P(H=h) = q_h \\
w \mid H \sim Dirichlet(\alpha) \\
\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_h \mid H=h \sim  \prod_{j=1}^h P_0(\theta_j)
$$

After running an MCMC simulation, we can get a point estimate the number of clusters, but also the latent partition of the data for example minimizing the Binder loss function, suppose that we obtain a partition estimate $\hat C_1, \ldots \hat C_K$ with $K$ clusters.

In order to report the results, one may be interested also in obtaining a point estimate for the cluster-specific parameters $\hat \theta_1, \ldots, \hat \theta_K$.
What are some possible ways to do so?

For instance, would it be ok to estimate $\hat \theta_1$ as the mode of the distribution $P_0(\theta) \times \prod_{i \in \hat C_1} f(y_i \mid \theta)$?

What happens if instead of assuming the $\theta$s independent, we assume a joint distribution on them (non independent)?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. The point estimates of $\theta$ are not obtained from the posterior (MCMC chains) as usual?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, one cannot estimate $\theta$ from the chain as it is, because of the "label switching" problem that makes the parameters non-identifiable. I know that for models with a fixed number of components one can use a deterministic relabeling of the chain and use that for point estimates, but I don't know if it's still a valid strategy when the number of component is random as well

Comment: This may help https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mapjg/papers/RichardsonGreenRSSB.pdf

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the paper, however it is not clear how to deal with varying number of mixture components in the MCMC chain and with multivariate parameters for which the order might not be unique...

Comment: Yes, it's not straightforward. Here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6347977.pdf (section 1.5) you can find more details about the possible solutions (model selection can be a simple approach, min KL divergence for instance). Also, there's a substantial risk of over-fitting, so you may want to try leave-one-out. The R package `bmixture` can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this reference, I was not aware of it and will read it more in detail. I think then a possibility would then be to minimize the KL divergence between the predictive distribution and a finite mixture with K clusters (K being the number of estimated clusters using e.g. the Binder loss)

Comment: Yes, have a look at the `bmixture` package. It can fit mixture models with unknown number of components, and it gives also the chains for the parameters https://rdrr.io/cran/bmixture/src/R/bmixnorm.R (for instance, normal distr). If you plan to use model comparison, be careful about over-fitting https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0131739. It can be good using the expected log pointwise predictive density with a leave-one-out.